# How to use Route in Controller Level

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Here i'm trying to call WebApi Controller using [Route] attribute

Why is `http://localhost:57997/Hello/Jan/1`  not a configured route
while `http://localhost:57997/Hello/Jan` Fetching data

```
using a = System.Web.Http;

[a.Route("Hello/Jan")]
public IEnumerable<Department> GetDepartmets()
{
    var x = pro.GetDept();
    return x.ToList();
}

[a.Route("Hello/Jan/{id?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetDepartmets(int id)
{
     if (id != null)
        {
            var x = pro.GetDeptById(id);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, x);
        }
        else
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

}
```

Comment: add a route constraint and see if it fixes the problem `[a.Route("Hello/Jan/{id:int?}")]`. You might also need to to include Http{Verb} ie: `[a.HttpGet]`. though the conventions should have picked it up based on action name

Comment: Can you show a more complete version of the controller?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal complete verifiable example based on your original post of what the controller can look like using attribute routing.

```
using a = System.Web.Http;

[a.RoutePrefix("Hello/Jan")] //RoutePrefix used to group common route on controller
public MyController : ApiController {

    //...other code removed for brevity. ie: pro    

    //GET Hello/Jan
    [a.HttpGet]
    [a.Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetDepartmets() {
        var departments = pro.GetDept().ToList();
        return Ok(departments);
    }

    //GET Hello/Jan/1
    [a.HttpGet]
    [a.Route("{id:int}")] //Already have a default route. No need to make this optional
    public IHttpActionResult GetDepartmet(int id) {
         var department = pro.GetDeptById(id);
         if (department != null) {
             return Ok(department);
         }

         return NotFound();    
    }
}
```

Note: Make sure that attribute routing is enabled in `WebApiConfig`

```
//enable attribute routing
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

//...before other convention-based routes.
```